# Extract CFKeyedArchiverUID value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist

I have a plist file in which some "objects" are contained. I can successfully extract a dictionary, but when I try to NSLog an objectForKey I got this kind of log:

```
<CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x608000228c20 [0x7fff75bddf00]>{value = 815}
```

how can I extract the value 815?

Maybe it can help knowing that 815 is a reference to a position of an item in the dictionary.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I can't find a solution I used a trick, I converted the object to a string and using regex I extracted the part between brackets {}. Here's the code, where value is an object in the NSDictionary:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\{(.*?)\\}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *result = [[[value objectForKey:@"artist"] description] substringWithRange:[regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:[[value objectForKey:@"artist"] description] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [[value objectForKey:@"artist"] description].length)]];
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this [opensource.apple.com source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.21/CFBinaryPList.c?txt), CFKeyedArchiverUID is a struct:

```
struct __CFKeyedArchiverUID {
  CFRuntimeBase _base;
  uint32_t _value;
};
```

And CFRuntimeBase is 16 bits. ([opensource.apple.com source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-299/Base.subproj/CFRuntime.c))

So you can get the value for a CFKeyedArchiverUID object by skipping the first 16 bits and getting the uint32_t value at that address:

```
+ (uint32_t)valueForKeyedArchiverUID: (id)keyedArchiverUID {
    void *uid = (__bridge void*)keyedArchiverUID;
    uint32_t *valuePtr = uid+16;
    return *valuePtr;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks this worked but do you also know how to create and add a CFKeyedArchiverUID with a custom value to a NSDictionary?

Comment: Just a note that CFRuntimeBase is not really 16 bits; it's the size of a pointer plus 32 bits. See `struct __CFRuntimeBase` in [CFRuntime.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-299/Base.subproj/CFRuntime.h). Otherwise good answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A proper hack to solve this is to do a similar thing as [Lucasware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4831495/lucasware) suggested:

1. In your source, declare this:

   ```c
   // we know this exists in CoreFoundation
   uint32_t _CFKeyedArchiverUIDGetValue(id uid);
   ```
2. Then use it like this (i.e.):

   ```c
   NSUInteger objDictIdx =
         _CFKeyedArchiverUIDGetValue(fileData[@"$top"][@"root"]);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes I found @Andrew's answer to be the best for your job but just in case you want to know how to **create** a CFKeyedArchiverUID, I finally figured out how to do it.

1. Include CoreFoundation in your project and import it in the files:

   ```
   #import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
   ```
2. In the source file insert the following somewhere (maybe between imports and classes) :

   ```
   id _CFKeyedArchiverUIDCreate(CFAllocatorRef allocator, uint32_t value);
   ```
3. In the method you want to create a KeyedArchiverUID simply use this:

   ```
   uint32_t value = ...; // Value here

   id uid = _CFKeyedArchiverUIDCreate(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), value);
   ```

Hope this helps anyone looking how to create KeyedArchiverUID's

Comment: This is a good answer. Perhaps you could ask a new question about _creating_ `CFKeyedArchiverUID`s and post this as an answer there, for better visibility?